# Possible to set the virtual address space limits?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

My current problem is that I have to decide if a memory address belongs to process A or B. Therefore the only solution that comes to my mind is to run the processes in distinct virtual address spaces (with that I mean the processes should use different ranges for their virtual addresses) but I don't know if this is possible or not.

**Example:**
Lets say that process A has its own virtual address space and uses virtual addresses in the range of 0 to 10. Process B similarly has its own virtual address space and uses virtual addresses in the same range. Now I have a third party that gets such an address and has to decide to which process it belongs. If process A would only use virtual addresses in the range of 0 to 4 and process B in the range of 5 to 10, then the third party could easily tell to which process the address belongs.

Comment: From which perspective, and why, are you asking that question? Are you coding a kernel module (I hope not)?

Comment: Every single process runs in it's own entirely separate (virtual) address space, entailing addresses from 0 to 2^32-1 (or 2^64-1). There is no way to tell, given a specific address, from which process that address came, as many different processes may actually have that address in use. If you are acquiring raw pointers from a process via IPC or network or other means, then you need to seriously rethink some design issues...

Comment: Right, but is there a possibility to limit the virtual addresses in use to e.g. 0 to 2^31 for one process and 2^31 to 2^32-1 for the other process?

Comment: In the general case, no - you might be able to achieve something like that with lots of extra options passed to your compiler, assembler, and linker, but it's going to be fragile, and if you ever want to scale to three or more processes, it's going to be a major headache. The better solution would be to fix the "third party that gets such an address and has to decide to which process it belongs" - that's IMHO a very poor design approach. Perhaps a higher level description of what you're really trying to accomplish would be a good idea...

Comment: Well I understand that it seems to be a poor design without more information about what I want to accomplish. Anyway I have no influence on this "design" and just wanted to know if this possibility exists. Your answer helps me so I have to look for other ways.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, each  (Linux or Posix) [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its own (virtual) [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), and executes its (user-land) instructions in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Hence address `0x1234567` in process A does not refer to the same memory as the identical address `0x1234567` in process B.

<sup>Of course the *physical* addresses are different, thanks to the MMU</sup>

So different processes have distinct address spaces. They might perhaps share some segments using [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory), but that is not very common. See e.g. [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Read about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and try

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

to understand the address space of the process running that `cat` command. Then try

```
cat /proc/$$/maps
```

to understand the address space of your shell process, and

```
cat /proc/$(pidof Xorg)/maps
```

to understand the address space of your [Xorg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) server.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Notice that only the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) manages and cares about *physical* addresses (those for [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) modules). Read more about [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s.

The [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_AS` can be used to limit address space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added an example to my question to make it more clear what I actually want.

Comment: Again, each process has its own address space.

Comment: I know that equal addresses in different processes do not refer to the same memory and thats also the point. I also understand the concept of virtual addresses. It is hard for me to describe it in another way than the example I gave. If I give you address 0x1234567, two processes and one try to read the result from the "right" process, than you could not decide which process contains the result except both processes would use different address ranges in their own virtual address space. Is it possible to tell process A to only use addresses in the range of e.g. 0x0000000 to 0x2000000?